# GLSL error log gives wrong line numbers on NVIDIA

Tags: glsl, nvidia

If I compile GLSL shaders on my desktop computer which contains an NVIDIA graphics card the line numbers in the error message wrong. It always seems to be the actual line number plus three.
On my laptop computer, which contains an ATI graphics card, the line numbers are correct.

Take the following simple GLSL fragment shader for example. It contains an error in line 6, where `texture2D` is written with a double t.

```
uniform sampler2D   dirt;
varying vec3    pos;

void main()
{
    vec3 d = ttexture2D(dirt, pos.xy).rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(d, 1.0);
}
```

The NVIDIA compiler gives me the following error message:

```
0(9) : error C1008: undefined variable "ttexture2D"
```

The ATI compiler displays the correct line numbers:

```
Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 1:6: error(#202) No matching overloaded function found ttexture2D
ERROR: 1:6: error(#216) Vector field selection out of range 'rgb'
ERROR: error(#273) 2 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

Is there a reason why the NVIDIA compiler gives me wrong line numbers?

EDIT: I am using NVIDIA driver version 331.58

Comment: NV's GLSL compiler is a very strange beast to begin with. If you do not explicitly include `#version XYZ` at the top of a shader, NV's compiler deviates from the GLSL spec. by allowing you to use non-GLSL constructs (Cg, specifically). A normal GLSL compiler would assume that the shader was written against GLSL 110 in such a situation, but NV actually translates GLSL to Cg before compiling and this is where things often get really weird. Can you try adding `#version 110` to the top of the shader, and if that changes nothing, possibly `#line 1` after `#version 110`?

Comment: `#version 110` did not change anything, but `#line 1` actually worked, thank you :) The problem now is that I wanted to use the line number to highlight the line that contains the error in a `QPlainTextEdit`. And I do not want to force the user to always type `#line 1` at the beginning of the shader.

Comment: This is a bloody awful hack, but you could write an addition to your software that pre-pends "#line 1\n" to the top of any shader string it is passed. Note that this pre-processor directive has to come **after** "#version XYZ\n" (if it exists in the shader), so you would have to parse the shader to search for a `#version` directive (and also compensate for the extra line in your number). Again this is a total hack, and I do not know for sure why NV's compiler is giving you incorrect line numbers, or I would try to submit this as an answer.

Comment: That could actually work, but NV's compiler also counts `#version XXX\n` and `#line 1\n` as a line, so I would have to scan the error string and decrement the line numbers there before I present it to the user (which is also done besides the highlighting of the line). Another possibility would be check the vendor of the graphics card and subtract three from the line numbers if it is NVIDIA :D

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure the `#version XXX` line would never be the source of an error. The whole point of `#line` is to tell the GLSL compiler that every line after this directive starts from that particular number. Used correctly, you can use it to match line numbers up properly. The only thing I can honestly think of is that the Cg compiler is adding lines like `#pragmaNV (unroll: ALL)` to the top of the shader without your knowledge, or you have mixed line-ending characters in your shader and this is confusing the Cg compiler (GLSL is supposed to handle \r\n and \n together gracefully).

Comment: That Cg adds some NVIDIA specific lines to the beginning of the shader was also my guess, but I did not find anything about it on Google. That's why I asked here if someone knows what's going on. The newline characters are all \r\n by the way.